# Ubuntu/Debian/OpenSSH: Run (system) script on SSH login and/or logout

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, ssh

On Ubuntu, I'd like my OpenSSH server to start a script whenever a user logs in using SSH, ideally passing the host name or IP, as well as the user name. Additionally I'd like it to run a script, whenever a session is terminated (passing the username). These scripts should not run in the user's session, but system wide.

The idea is to give an audio warning on login and logout, e.g. using `espeak`, and to display the information on an external display.

I've seen that there is a `pam-scripts` package but I'm not sure if this does what I want, nor how to use it.

Any help is appreciated!
-- Markus

(I also posted this question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10294/run-system-script-on-ssh-login-and-or-logout).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a wrapper script to be called by ForceCommand in sshd_config.  This differentiates between a login command and a command invoked via ssh like `ssh host "ls -l"`, since you might want to handle those differently.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then
    eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
else
    echo "LOGIN: $USER $SSH_CONNECTION" >> /tmp/ssh.log
    $SHELL
    echo "LOGOUT: $USER $SSH_CONNECTION" >> /tmp/ssh.log
fi
```

You can replace the echo commands with whatever you'd like.  IP information is in `$SSH_CONNECTION`, do with it what you will.

If you call this `/usr/local/bin/ssh-command.sh`, you would add this to your `sshd_config`:

```
ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/ssh-command.sh
```

It is probably a good idea to use `Match` as well to only trap certain users.  Assuming all the users are in the "gobias" group:

```
Match Group gobias
    ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/ssh-command.sh
```

Anyway, perhaps it's worth a shot.

Comment: +1 for the Match conditional block, nice

Comment: Very nice, thanks! But do you have an idea of how to run the script as root. I need to perform chown `root:root` on some user files upon logging in?

Comment: You could probably do something with a nopasswd sudo command to address that.  I'm not certain there's an easy way to do it through sshd directly, so sudo would probably be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a script to do whatever you want and then stick it in `/etc/profile` or possibly`/etc/bash.bashrc` depending on your needs. Changes to those files will apply to all users. I'm not sure how you'd go about notifying on logout with this approach, though.

Alternatively, another way to do this would be to have a simple daemon monitoring `/var/log/secure` (or `/var/log/auth`, depending on which distro you're using)for new (and closing) ssh sessions. That way it would be able to send notifications on both login and logout.

Answer (score 1):

If the file /etc/ssh/sshrc exists, it is run by sh(1) after reading the user's environment but before starting the user's shell or command. See `man sshd`.

E.g., the following added to /etc/ssh/sshrc will produce the output shown when a user logs in successfully via OpenSSH:

```
~$ cat /etc/ssh/sshrc
echo "Login by $USER from $SSH_CLIENT on `date`" >> /var/log/ssh_connections.log
```

Output in /var/log/ssh_connections.log:

```
Login by Markus from 10.0.0.1 57853 22 on Fri Oct 29 03:41:31 2010
```

Comment: Be careful -- this would be ignored if the user had their own ~/.ssh/rc file.

Comment: @Cakemox You are correct. Not sure how to get around that :-\